# Can you remember the name of a public access Unix system, around 1990/1, Spug or Spud?

Tags: unix, identify-this-software

Hey I recall accessing a public-access UNIX system in the UK, likely around 1990/91.
I seem to recall it gave you shell access but it might actually have only been Mail or UUCP/usenet client?

I have a feeling the name was something like Spug or Spud Net or something? Can anyone recall its name. I also have a feeling it went through a subtle name change too?

Any info gratefully received.

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to post "No" as an answer to the question posed in the title  :-)

Answer (score 11):

[Spud's Public Usenet Domain](https://www.spuddy.org/Previous/old-website/), aka Spuddy, or Spud's Xanadu - formerly run by [Stephen Harris](https://www.sweharris.org/about/). Featuring (and quoted from the page):

> - Spuddy offers the only online full usenet/mail service for free in the UK. A growing system, now running on a Sun Sparc 2, Spuddy
>   represents a high speed fast-expanding system.
> - Why not give it a call?!
> - Thousands of other users to talk to, averaging 400 users a week
> - Over 2 gig of stuff to download or request by post. This includes a complete archive of GNU freeware, mirrored from prep.ai.mit.edu
> - Two `mud' games.
> - FREE access to a full Unix shell. The choices of shell are : sh, csh, bash, ksh, zsh, tcsh, etc.
> - If you don't like Unix - you don't have to touch it! There is a menu system that allows user-friendly access to the world of usenet ! Just
>   request a `menu' shell.
> - Full access to usenet news. This (obviously) includes posting.
> - Your own mailbox for worldwide internet/uucp mail.
> - No limit on downloading - no ratios or silly rules. You may request sources by post for free (providing you provide the media!)
> - No restriction for time spent online.
> - A friendly BBS.